# Kotlin MockK throws an NullPointerException

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, mockk

I am trying to Mock a class object:

```kotlin
val obj = mockk<MyClass>()
```

where my class is nothing special, just a complicated class with member variables and methods that implements an interface.

This throws an error:

> Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(boolean)" because "ao" is null

Not sure what to make of this. It seems like something is not accessible but I'm not sure what or how to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have an up to date version of mockk. I was on 1.3 when I got this error. I switched to 1.9.3 and got a different error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 59
```

Then I switched to 1.10.6 (latest version as of now) and the errors disappeared.